# What does the symbol ⇴ mean?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, turing-machines

I am studying Discrete Mathematics and I encountered this symbol $f:N^k$⇴$N$ in a function definition about Turing machines. What does it mean?

Comment: What book/lecture?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA
He writes the lectures on paper and sends them to us, so I don't know.
From what I've read so far, it seems that the sign denotes a partially defined function, aka. a partial function but I am not sure.

Comment: It makes sense... No [standard symbol used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA OK, thank you for the feedback! I really don't understand why the symbols my teacher uses differ from the official ones and why he uses them without explanation. When someone asks a question, he rarely answers back.

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Comment: The drawback of having so many [$\LaTeX$ symbols](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) available...